# Which version of .NET contains MAUI fixes?

Tags: maui

I have just started working on .NET MAUI and have come across a bug with the RadioButton spacing. Searching on this it looks like this is fixed by this PR:

Fix RadioButton DefaultTemplate #8292
https://github.com/dotnet/maui/pull/8292

However, I am a bit unclear as to which version of .NET these fixes have been implemented on?

Currently I'm using a .NET version 7 on Visual Studio for Mac 2022.

Any information would be helpful, I'm pretty new to MAUI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for using .NET MAUI!

This PR is a fix for [The margin between the mark and content of the radio button is too narrow. #8291](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/8291).

And you could find that samhouts added the **fixed-in-8.0.0-preview.3.8149** label on Apr 13.

That means this issue is fixed in .NET version 8.

Best regards!

Comment: Thank you for the explanation Liqun, that makes sense. On a side note I see that .NET 8 preview isn't supported in Visual Studio for Mac 2022; even if you use the Preview version. Sadly this means I can't test these improvements to MAUI. Appreciate you taking the time to help!

Comment: .NET8 is supported in VS for mac 2022. You could refer to [Announcing .NET MAUI in .NET 8 Preview 7: Keyboard Accelerators](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-dotnet-maui-in-dotnet-8-preview-7/#how-to-update)